# Jest - Mock method of default class exported as named component of a package module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

We have the below classes:

Component 1:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {foo} from 'blah'
import {bar} from 'blah-blah'

export default class Component1 extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...
    ...
  }

  ...
  ...

  save() {
    doSomeOp()
  }

  render() {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Component 2:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {foo} from 'blah'
import {bar} from 'blah-blah'

export default class Component2 extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...
    ...
  }

  ...
  ...

  render() {
  }
}
```

Now, we have the following components within a package module - '@foo-bar/package'. The index.js for this package is as below:

index.js:

```
import Component1 from './src/component1'
import Component2 from './src/component2'
export { Component1, Component2 }
```

This package is used in another component that I am trying to test. The code for this component is as below:

TestComponent:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Component1 } from '@foo-bar/package'

export function TestComponent(props) {
  ...
  ...

  return (
    <Component1 />   
  )
}
```

I have some logic in this `TestComponent` which triggers the `save()` method of `Component1`. What I intend to do is keep all the other properties of `Component1` the same, but only mock the `save()` method. How could that be done? Thanks!

```
jest.mock('@foo-bar/package', () => {
  ???
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import { Component1 } from '@foo-bar/package'

beforeAll(() => {
  jest.spyOn(Component1.prototype, 'save').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())
})
```